# Kotlin: How to rid of function overload boilerplate?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, overloading

I am working with overload functions in *Kotlin*.

In this schematic example, suppose a function whose only difference is the type of `view` that I pass to the function. One uses `TextView`, the other uses `Button`, so I have 2 different functions.

```
fun workWithViews(v:TextView,...){
   // code
}
fun workWithViews(v:Button,...){
   // same code!
}
```

In this case, the properties I use are the same (`isAllCaps`, `gravity`, etc.). The problem is that I have to place the same code twice, i.e., the whole code is exactly the same.

It happens because  `isAllCaps` (just like many other properties) it is not a general property of a `view`, but of some types of views

So it doesn't work, because obviously the compiler see the function parameter, not the real parameter.

I also can make  function with a `view` type parameter, with a big `when` with my type possibilities:

```
fun workWithTextView(v:View,...){
when{
 (v is TextView) -> {
    // code
  }
 (v is Button)  {
  // same code
  }
 } // when
}
```

The 2 solutions are terrible and generate duplicate code or boilerplate.

I can also do the `when` before each access to some  field, which makes things even worse. Now imagine if one has 5 similar types instead of 2, with many fields in common.

I read some suggestions to create `union types` in Kotlin. It would be great!

For instance:

```
fun workWithViews(v:(TextView, Button),...){
      // just one code repetition....
}
```

or

```
 union textBut = TextView , Button
 fun workWithViews(v:textBut ,...){
          // just one code repetition....
 }
```

In that case I would only have to test a certain type (`if (v is typeX)`) if I used something specific for that type.

Is there some best solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because due to the ammount of responses and OP comments it should belong to code review

Comment: @cutiko [Don't use the existence of Code Review as a reason to close a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400). From now on evaluate the question and use a reason like; needs focus, primarily opinion-based, etc. This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it is missing context. Please familiarize yourself with what is [on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and our [guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778).

Answer (score 3):

`Button` is a subclass of `TextView`, so you can make the function signature take a `TextView` and put `Button`-specific stuff in an if-block.

```
fun workWithTextView(textView: TextView) {
    // Do stuff common to TextViews and Buttons.

    if (textView is Button) {
        // Do extra stuff only for Buttons.
    }
}
```

Comment: @IR42 Most likely, yes, but it could possibly depend on what this function is actually used for. IMO, it would be better still not to overload, but rather use different function names when the differing parameters are in an hierarchy (just for clarity). Otherwise, it can be ambiguous. `val foo: TextView = Button(); workWithTextView(foo);` In this case, you might have to look up language documentation to remember which overload will be called.

Comment: Yes, but it is a real case, where one control is a `button` and the other is a `text view`, WHERE all 8 commands do exactly the same thing with the same fields. But I've got it: in this case I can make a textView function and pass my button view with no problem

Comment: Because this function set only text attributes in many source code locations. However,  sometimes it's a `Button` and sometimes it's a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

If Views have common methods, then most likely one view extends the other.
For example, Button extends TextView and you can do this:

```
fun workWithViews(v:TextView){
   // TextView code
}
fun workWithViews(v:Button){
   // Button specific code
   workWithViews(v as TextView)
}
```

Comment: I've commented above. It's a real case, where one control is a button and the other is a text view, WHERE all 8 commands do exactly the same thing with the same fields. But, according to the above answer, I can make a `textView` function and pass my button view with no problem

Comment: However, no `if` will remain. Just make a function `workWithViews` for `Textview` and pass a button in the caller. In this case, I only handle text attributes inside function